# Scalatra, Atmosphere, and sending messages to clients from outside the message handler

Tags: scala, websocket, atmosphere, scalatra

I'm currently reading through the official Scalatra documentation, particularly the [guide on using Scalatra with Atmosphere](http://scalatra.org/guides/async/atmosphere.html). That page explains how to use Scalatra and Atmosphere to write a WebSocket based application which responds to incoming messages with outgoing messages.

For the purposes of an application which connects multiple different messaging sources, how would I send outgoing messages from elsewhere in the application?

Possible examples include:

- messages sent as a result of an incoming HTTP request
- periodic messages on a timer
- messages pulled from a queue
- etc.

Some of these messages could potentially target multiple clients.

I'm a bit confused by the official docs on this matter because all the examples happen various incoming message handlers and I'm not sure where to get a reference to the Atmosphere system or where/how I'm allowed to call it.

I Hope someone can clarify.